# React router render called even when path is not matched for the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a parent component where I have a router with routes. Each route is wrapped with the `ProtectedRoute` component that checks if the component should be rendered or not.

```
       const matchedPath = this.props.match.path;
       return (
       <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute
            path={`${matchedPath}/start`}
            status={this.state.exam.status}
            requiredState="NOT_STARTED"
            component={StartExamPage}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            path={`${matchedPath}/task/:count`}
            status={this.state.exam.status}
            requiredState="STARTED"
            component={ExamPage}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            path={`${matchedPath}/summary`}
            status={this.state.exam.status}
            requiredState="STARTED"
            component={Summary}
            exam={this.exam.prove}
            navigateToTask={this.navigateToTask}
            logAction={this.logAction}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
     </Switch>)
```

The `ProtectedRoute` component looks like this:

```
class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component {
  examStatusDefaultUrl(status) {
    switch (status) {
      case 'NOT_STARTED':
        return '/exam/start';
      case 'STARTED':
        return '/exam/summary'; 
      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid state: '${status}'`)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...componentProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route
        {...componentProps}
        render={props => {
          return (
            componentProps.status === componentProps.requiredState ?
            <Component {...componentProps} {...props}/> :
            <Redirect to={this.examStatusDefaultUrl(componentProps.status)}/>
        )}}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Since I want to log when the each page is opened, I am calling a `logAction` function from the `componentDidUpdate` in Summary component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    console.log('summary ', this.props);
    this.props.logAction({action: actions.SUMMARY_OPENED});
}
```

The problem I have is that the `Summary's` `componentDidMount` is called even when the component is not mounted. It is called when the `task/:count` route is rendered. They have the same value of the `status` that I check to determine if the component is going to be rendered or not in the `ProtectedRoute` component. So, I wonder if that is the problem and how can I solve it, so that the `componentDidMount` is called only when the component is actually mounted and rendered?